# Laravel - Get all records, not just first?

Tags: php, laravel

today I am facing a problem with Laravel. What I want to do is get every 'stat' value for every record where government_type = higher_government. By the way, I am different types, but this is just one of many.

```
$higherGovernment = Cache::remember('government.higher_government', 1, function() {
    return GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->first()->stats;
});
```

How can I get all the stats for all types instead of just calling ->first() ?

I have tried removing the ->first() but it doesn't do anything except give me this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$stats
```

stats is a relationship by the way:

```
    public function stats(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Website\User\Roleplay', 'government_id');
   }
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all() ??

Comment: That results in the same error as I get when I remove first().

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$stats

Comment: I have tried that, I get this. Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
\App\YourModelName::select('fields')->where('condition')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one column from this table, you can use the [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) function to indicate wich ones you want.

Like so:

```
<?php
    $higherGovernment = Cache::remember('government.higher_government', 1, function() {
        return GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->select('stats')->get();
    });
```

The collection `$higherGovernment` will now contain `GovernmentRole` objects with one parameter, `stats`.

If you would like this to be an array of only the stats property, you can use collections to [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) this value out of it. Like so:

```
<?php
    $higherGovernment = Cache::remember('government.higher_government', 1, function() {
        return GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->select('stats')->get()->pluck('stats');
    });
```

**Update:**

Now that we know that stats is a relation I think the best solution is to just load all `GovernmentRole` objects and [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relation. Then you can display the stats for every `GovernmentRole`.

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $higherGovernment = Cache::remember('government.higher_government', 1, function() {
        return GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->with('stats')->get();
    });

    // Just an example on how to get the stats
    foreach ($g in $higherGovernment)
        echo $g->stats->count();
```

Comment: I tried using this. I get the following error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user

Comment: I'm hoping you realize that stat() is a relationship, and not a column.

Comment: public function stats(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Website\User\Roleplay', 'government_id');
   }

Comment: Maybe you should have put that in your question, this changes the question entirely...

Comment: That was very foolish of me, I apologize.

Comment: When ever I try and do this, I simply get: Trying to get property of non-object (in the view)

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is do a select right in the relationship, I think, like this:

```
public function stats(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Website\User\Roleplay', 'government_id')->select('stats')->get(); 
}
```

This would in that case remove the relation, but you'd get the stats. Another way to do it is to just, straight away, get the stats from the relationship like this:

```
GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->first()->stats->select('stats')->get();
```

or if that gives you an error try:

```
GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->first()->stats()->select('stats')->get();
```

Comment: I get 'Method select does not exist.' error when doing the second code option, but I won't try the 3rd as its the same. I wouldn't want to do the first as I need to do the first and all for different controllers.

Comment: You could always separate out the "Roleplay" model to a separate relation maybe called "roles" and then have a second one for stats. Really though, I would just skip out on using relations and just access the model directly, e.g. `Roleplay::where('some_post', 'some_value')->select('stats')->get();`

Comment: Right, you're getting Method does not exist because it's not an eloquent query builder object, my bad there. Though you could use pluck as @Jerodev pointed out.